# When I use jdbc to create SQL database , getting this error. where I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I write methods for createConnection and createDatabase in class methods. Connection is getting created successfully but database is not creating because of wrong input for SQL query.

```
class methods{
    
    public static Connection CreateConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
     {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","baby");
        System.out.println("connected to Mysql database");
        return con;
    }

    public static void createDatabase(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Enter database name :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String q1 = "CREATE DATABASE ?";
        PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(q1);
        String databasename = sc.next();
        smt.setString(1, databasename);
        smt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Database created.");
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection con = methods.CreateConnection();
    methods.createDatabase(con);
}
```

Output

```
Enter database name :
data
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''data'' at line 1
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1109)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1057)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1377)
    at mysql.connector.java@8.0.15/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at jdbc.methods.createDatabase(methods.java:28)
    at jdbc.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: ......you cant do CREATE DATABASE ''%data%'..... it should be CREATE DATABASE yourDatabaseName.   Without %%. ..

Comment: after removing % ,same error is showing

Comment: I'm not sure if your concept of creating databases programmatically is a good one but conceptually you *don't* have a prepared statement (statement with bind variable) there. Try a normal `Statement` and just do `"CREATE DATABASE " + sc.next()`

Comment: You cannot use parameters for object names like a database name, only for values. In most JDBC driver implementations, you'd already get an error when preparing the statement, but by default the MySQL driver uses client-side prepared statements, replacing the parameters with string literals on execute.

Answer (score 0):

Print `PreparedStatement` to see the problem origin:

```
System.out.println(smt);
smt.executeUpdate();
```

Assuming that user entered `StudentDB` as database name, printed statement would be:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'StdudentDB'
```

That is invalid and should be:

```
CREATE DATABASE StdudentDB
```